# Problems in understanding the result of this composition of automorphisms

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let be p a prime number and let be $|x|=p^{n-1}$.

I consider $\alpha \in {\rm Aut}(\langle x \rangle)$ defined in this way:
$\alpha : x \mapsto x^{1+p}$.

Let be $\gamma=\alpha^{p^{n-3}}$.

I don't understand why $\gamma: x \mapsto x^{1+p^{n-2}}$.

Why is it not  $\gamma(x)=x^{{(1+p)}^{{p}^{n-3}}}$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Should the $2$ in the first line be $p$?

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, I've edited the question

Comment: Then $(1+p)^{p^{n-3}} \equiv 1 + p^{n-2} \bmod p^{n-1}$ and the result follows from $x^{p^{n-1}}=1$.